# Highcharts javascript control series

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, highcharts

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called M Chart which uses HighCharts to display a line chart with 5 line graphs on one chart.

I have created a few buttons which when clicked I want to hide certain Series on the chart. I have tried all sorts but cant get it working! Any ideas?

```
// Buttons
<div class="vid-chart-button only-reset">Reset All</div>
<div class="vid-chart-button only-totals">Only show Totals</div> </br>
<div class="vid-chart-button only-app">Only show App</div>
<div class="vid-chart-button only-events">Only show Events</div>
<div class="vid-chart-button only-sos">Only show SOS</div>
<div class="vid-chart-button only-magazine">Only show Magazine</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){  



$(".only-totals").click(function(){
    var chart = Highcharts.chart(".m-chart", {});
     $(chart.series[1]).hide();


}); 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows how to use an outside button

```
// Declare you chart
var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();

// Declare each button you want
$('#only-europe').on('click',function(){
    myChart.series[0].hide();
    myChart.series[1].hide();
    myChart.series[3].hide();
    myChart.series[4].hide();
});
```

[Updated Fiddle - Thanks Patata](http://jsfiddle.net/org8czhr/1/)

Comment: Thanks Core972. I just tried that but it's not working! // Declare you chart
        var myChart = $('#highcharts-i0c2d2u-0').highcharts();

       $('#only-totals').on('click',function(){
    myChart.series[0].hide();
    myChart.series[1].hide();
    myChart.series[3].hide();
    myChart.series[4].hide();
      });

Comment: @JamesBernhard update like http://jsfiddle.net/org8czhr/1/ declare `var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();` after highcharts initialization

Comment: @Patata, You are right I changed the fiddle before saving the first fiddle. I updated my answer to link to your fiddle.

Comment: Still not working - The script is inside a HTML/JS box inside of a page in Wordpress and it's still not fireing (it's using WP bakery). Should I be placing this JS somewhere else (like in the plugin JS file) ?

Comment: Got it working! Needed to put the script in a differnt location below the Chart as it was rendering the charge after the script.